# Updating tag wiki on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, tagwiki

Recently there has been a discussion on Meta Stack Overflow (again) about whether to ask LaTeX questions on Stack Overflow or on TeX.SE.

I answered that question (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415691/) stating that at TeX.SE we welcome questions about LaTeX itself, tools and libraries that produce LaTeX code like pylatex and knitr, and export-to-latex functions in other tools, but that questions about MathJax and KaTeX are off-topic on TeX.SE and should be asked on Stack Overflow instead.

Another user suggested in a comment that the tag wiki for [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) on Stack Overflow should be updated to reflect the above guidelines, to inform visitors on Stack Overflow whether they should ask their question there or at TeX.SE.

Currently that [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/latex/info), curated by Werner in 2018, does mention that TeX.SE exists and that questions about "LaTeX and related technologies" are better asked on TeX.SE than on Stack Overflow, but no further details are provided.

**Question**: do you think we should edit that tag wiki to mention MathJax and KaTeX specifically as topics to be asked about on Stack Overflow and not on TeX.SE, and/or to explain what the scope of "related technologies" is?

Further question: do you think we should edit the wiki for [katex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/katex) and [mathjax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax) on our own site to suggest people with a question about these two libraries to ask on Stack Overflow instead?

If you want you can answer this Meta question with a suggested wording for edits to the relevant tag wikis.

---

Update: after several weeks my edit suggestion on Stack Overflow is finally approved :)

Comment: These sound like good suggestions. I'm not sure whether they will have any real effect on people's posting behaviour, but it certainly can't harm.

Comment: I hadn't actually noticed his question but I did add a note to the mathjax tag wiki a while back